# how connect to git server over ssh

Tags: git, ssh

I have Linux machine server which it is in Domain,and is connected in a LAN network, I have a centos7 Virtual Machine on my computer which it isn't in domain, I want to connect to Linux machine server over LAN network and push my git with ssh command. but I can't. Is there any solution?

```
$ git clone ssh://git@10.100.184.17:22/hostextera.git 
Error :  does not appear to be a git repository 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Comment: port 22 implied by ssh://. Also, ensure the repository exists on that path and that ip is reachable

Comment: Are you sure to connect to your centos VM? Or do you connect only to the hosting machine?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : check that you can connect to that linux machine through ssh using this `git` user account :

```
ssh git@10.100.184.17
```

Step 2 : the `hostextera` repository on that linux server is a regular directory, you should provide a path which correctly points to that directory

```
# either a relative one :
#   the part after the '/' will be relative to the home directory of the
#   `git` user home directory :
git clone ssh://git@10.100.184.17:22/repos/hostextera.git

# or an absolute one :
git clone ssh://git@10.100.184.17:22//usr/share/repos/hostextera.git


# as @pygeek pointed out, 22 is the default ssh port, you can use shorter urls :
git clone git@10.100.184.17:repos/hostextera.git
git clone git@10.100.184.17:/usr/share/repos/hostextera.git
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to review the permissions on the git console, for the git user you are using. If you can access any other repository on the Git server, from your local PC.